# How to export multiple modules from single JS file in Cordova/PhoneGap Plugin?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, requirejs, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a custom Cordova plugin. For some reason, I am restricted to expose all my JS objects through single JavaScript file only. Below sample JS replicating my Problem

```
My JS have 2 objects apple and orange, I have to export them from single file

var apple = function() {
        type: "macintosh",
        color: "red",
        getInfo: function () {
            return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
        };

 var orange = function() {
        color: "red2",
        show: function () {
           alert("test type 2 also passed dude !----");;
        }

        };
```

I am exporting them like this

```
    var apple1 = new apple();
     module.exports = apple1;

    var orange1 = new orange();
     module.exports = orange1;
```

My problem is orange1 is overriding apple1 export. How to export both `apple1` and `orange1` using `module.exports`? or there any other way?

Please provide me some inputs. Any samples are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Following approach worked for me.

```
var apple1 = new apple();
var orange1 = new orange();
var myExports = module.exports;
    myExports .apple1 = apple1;
    myExports .orange1 = orange1;
```